# Wrapper functions for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a project that has already been written using context of data.frame. In order to improve calc times I'm trying to leverage the speed of using data.table instead. My methodology for this has been to construct wrapper functions that read in frames, convert them to tables, do the calculations and then convert back to frames. Here's one of the simple examples...

```
FastAgg<-function(x, FUN, aggFields, byFields = NULL, ...){
  require('data.table')
  y<-setDT(x)
  y<-y[,lapply(X=.SD,FUN=FUN,...),.SDcols = aggFields,by=byFields]
  y<-data.frame(y)
  y
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after running this function x has been converted to a table and then lines of code that I have written using data.frame notation fail. How do I make sure that the data.frame I feed in is unchanged by the running function?

Comment: Wow, even doing this changes the original data.frame, which I didn't expect: `dat <- data.frame(a=1); dat2 <- dat; setDT(dat2); is.data.table(dat);` That seems buggy to me to be honest.

Comment: Use `as.data.table` instead of `setDT`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - that does seem to work. I gather `setDT` causes issues because it is changing the object without copying, which `<-` might not do in my example either until something else acts on it.

Comment: @thelatemail, if you review the R Public room, I was asking Arun about something related recently. The recommendation was to use `as.data.table` for `data.frame`s and `copy` for `data.table`s within the functions.

Comment: For reference: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/conversation/data-table-copy-as-data-table

Comment: I don't see any assignment of the results of that function to a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, I'd recommend (of course) to use `data.table` through out and not just in a function :-).

But if it's not likely to happen, then I'd recommend the `setDT` + `setDF` setup. I'd recommend using `setDT` outside the function (and provide the data.table as input) - to convert your data.frame to a data.table by reference, and then after finishing the operations you'd like, you can use `setDF` to convert the result back to a data.frame using `setDF` and return that from the function. However, doing `setDT(x)` changes `x` to a data.table - as it operates by reference.

If that is not ideal, then use `as.data.table(.)` inside your function, as it operates on a copy. Then, you can still use `setDF()` to convert the resulting data.table to data.frame and return that data.frame from your function.

These functions are recently introduced (mostly due to user requests). The idea to avoid this confusion is to export `shallow()` function and keep track of objects that require columns to be copied, and do it all internally (and automatically). It's all in very early stages right now. When we've managed, I'll update this post.

---

Also have a look at `?copy`, `?setDT` and `?setDF`. The first paragraph in these function's help page is:

> In `data.table` parlance, all `set*` functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory, which is as large as one column.. The only other `data.table` operator that modifies input by reference is `:=`. Check out the `See Also` section below for other `set*` function data.table provides.

And the example for `setDT`:

```
set.seed(45L)
X = data.frame(A=sample(3, 10, TRUE), 
         B=sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE), 
         C=sample(10), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# get the frequency of each "A,B" combination
setDT(X)[, .N, by="A,B"][]
```

does no assignment (although I admit it could be explained slightly better here).

In `setDF`:

```
X = data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
## convert 'X' to data.frame, without any copy.
setDF(X)
```

I think this is pretty clear. But I'll try to provide more clarity. Also, I'll try and add how best to use these functions in the documentation as well.

Comment: I can appreciate your recommendation to simply use data.table throughout, both because the learning curve seems less (coming from a SQL background) and because the speed is so much better. I'm sure, of course, that you can understand that I don't want to have to rewrite all of my code for all of my projects. :-P