# When selecting "top n" columns from data.table or head(), R returns levels from underlying vector

Tags: r, data.table, head

I have a df of fishing data:

```
| year | taxon_name    | amount (tonnes) |
 1950    Gadus morhua    100
 1951    Gadus morhua    120
 1952    Gadus morhua    140
 1953    Gadus morhua    130
 1954    Gadus morhua    210
 1950    Sebastes        234
 1951    Sebastes        123
 1952    Sebastes        627
 1953    Sebastes        542
 1954    Sebastes        303
```

... etc.

I know how to select the top 4 fished species using several methods, such as using `data.table`:

`top4 <- setDT(discards_tax)[, .(amount = sum(amount)), by = taxon_name][order(-amount)][1:4, , ] # aggregate catch by taxon, order from highest to lowest catch & grab the top 4`

Or using `aggregate` with `order` and `head()`:

```
top4d <- aggregate(amount ~ taxon_name, discards_tax, sum) # aggregate catch by taxon
top4d <- top4d[order(-top4d$amount),] %>% head(4) # order df from highest to lowest catch & grab the top 4
```

Both cases produce this successful result, with the old row numbers:

```
rowid | taxon_name                   | amount
   33   Melanogrammus aeglefinus       14922534
   60   Sebastes                       14274663
   25   Gadus morhua                   6237214
   53   Reinhardtius hippoglossoides   2466558
```

My problem is that after this, I've been trying to make a vector list of the `taxon_name`s that are the top 4 - but every single time I try and do this (i.e. `toptaxa <- top4d$taxon_name`) it spits out all 67 original taxa from my fishing dataset! Originally I thought this was a design feature of `data.table` but seeing as this is occurring regardless of what method I'm using it's clear I'm not understanding it correctly.

Similar questions have been asked before (e.g. [Why does selecting column(s) from a data.table results in a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873299/why-does-selecting-columns-from-a-data-table-results-in-a-copy)) but I'm not sure I've seen an answer that lets me select from only my results. How can I manipulate only the results of my top 4 sorting?

**EDIT** here is my dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/izn7sdpeosvg1nj/discards_for_stack.csv?dl=0

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong (original) variable to query not the top 4 result but the original data set? Please add a MRE that reproduces this behaviour!

Comment: the toptaxa <- top4$taxon_name worked fine here.

Comment: @spops I have shown in my answer using 3 different methods that results are fairly consistent and it returns only 4 top items. Have a look. perhaps something wrong in your data and use of variables.

Comment: Thanks @MKR, will check it out and try with my dataset. I have added a link to the original dataset to the bottom of my post as well

Comment: @spops I tried with data shared by you. It works fine. I have updated my answer with result. Have a look.

Comment: As usual with programming it was a dumb but easily solved issue that just needed fresh eyes! Leaving this question up in case anybody else has another case like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
top4 <- setDT(df)[, .(amount = sum(amount)), by = taxon_name][order(-amount)][1:4, ]

toptaxa <- top4$taxon_name
#[1] "Sebastes"     "dummy2"       "dummy1"       "Gadus morhua"
```

`Base-R` aggregate approach:

```
top4d <- aggregate(amount ~ taxon_name, df, sum)
top4d <- top4d[order(-top4d$amount),] %>% head(4)

toptaxa <- top4d$taxon_name

toptaxa
#[1] "Sebastes"     "dummy2"       "dummy1"       "Gadus morhua"
```

Lets check another option using `dplyr` package to summarize data and finally use `slice` to get top 4 species.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(taxon_name) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount.tonnes.)) %>%
  arrange(desc(amount)) %>%
  slice(1:4) %>%
  select(taxon_name) -> TopNames

#Check the result
TopNames

# # A tibble: 4 x 1
# taxon_name  
# <chr>       
# 1 Sebastes    
# 2 dummy2      
# 3 dummy1      
# 4 Gadus morhua
```

**Edited: *Using data shared by `OP`***

```
df <- read.csv("D:\\Learning\\R\\discards_for_stack.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
top4d <- aggregate(amount ~ taxon_name, df, sum)
top4d <- top4d[order(-top4d$amount),] %>% head(4)

top4d
#                      taxon_name   amount
# 33     Melanogrammus aeglefinus 14922534
# 60                     Sebastes 14274663
# 25                 Gadus morhua  6237214
# 53 Reinhardtius hippoglossoides  2466558

toptaxa <- top4d$taxon_name
toptaxa
# [1] "Melanogrammus aeglefinus"     "Sebastes"                     "Gadus morhua"                
# [4] "Reinhardtius hippoglossoides"
```

**Data:**  Few additional rows have been added in OP toy data set to make a sensible example.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"year  taxon_name     amount(tonnes)
1950    'Gadus morhua'    100
1951    'Gadus morhua'    120
1952    'Gadus morhua'    140
1953    'Gadus morhua'    130
1954    'Gadus morhua'    210
1950    Sebastes        234
1951    Sebastes        123
1952    Sebastes        627
1951    dummy1        123
1952    dummy1        627
1951    dummy2        567
1952    dummy2        627
1951    dummy3        567
1952    dummy4        627
1953    Sebastes        542
1954    Sebastes        303",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand my issue - you're totally right, I am selecting the top 4, so thanks for clearing that up - it's that it's keeping all 67 levels despite using `droplevels(toptaxa)`. Changed it to `factor(toptaxa)` and everything works now!

Comment: Yes. May be you have not used stringsAsFactors = FALSE while reading from cab.

Comment: Yep, did not do that.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this with `data.table` is as follows. I'm using `data.table::CJ` to generate a cartesian join of a handful of `taxon_name` options and a 5 year sequence, then populating the `amount` randomly.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1234)

DT <- CJ(year = seq.int(1950L,1954L,1L),
        taxon_name = c("Gadus morhua","Sebastes","Melanogrammus aeglefinus",
                       "Reinhardtius hippoglossoides","Foo","Bar","Baz"))


DT[, amount := sample.int(100, .N)]
setkey(DT,taxon_name)

print(DT[sample(.N,5)])

#    year                   taxon_name amount
# 1: 1951 Reinhardtius hippoglossoides     25
# 2: 1951                          Baz     99
# 3: 1953                          Baz     13
# 4: 1951                     Sebastes     81
# 5: 1950 Reinhardtius hippoglossoides     97

Top4 <- DT[,.(amount = sum(amount)), by = .(taxon_name)][order(-amount)][1:4,taxon_name]

print(Top4)

# [1] "Sebastes" "Baz" "Melanogrammus aeglefinus" "Gadus morhua"
```